# How to set uitableviewcellselectionstyle.none to static cells?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Sorry I really cant find this anywhere.

I need to set my selection style to none so that the rows dont highlight when i click on it. Also, i need rows to be selectable as I have some rows which needs expanding and collapsing. I know the piece of code is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` but I have no idea where I can implement it. Thanks!

**EDIT ADDED IN CODES**

```
        // MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 7
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // Set height for date picker

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        let height:CGFloat = datePicker.hidden ? 0.0 : 216.0
        return height

    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Expanding and collapsing date picker
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    let datePickerIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    if datePickerIndexPath == indexPath {

        datePicker.hidden = !datePicker.hidden

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            // apple bug fix - some TV lines hide after animation
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        })
    }
}
```

The codes are mainly for the datepicker that i have implemented. everything works fine but clicking on the cell highlights the whole row in the default selection color.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know where to best implement it without seeing your code, but you can definitely put it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you dequeue/initialize your cell. Just call `yourCell.selectionStyle = .None` before `return yourCell`

Comment: but currently my codes for table view data source is practically empty, because I am using static cells, there really isnt anything to show.
also, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can be used for static cells? I tried but the error came up 
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TransportExpenseCell0 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'"

Comment: and I do have a static cell with identifier TransportExpenseCell0

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.selectionStyle = .None
```

When you write the code after equal(=) , just press dot(.) so that many type of functionality will be pop up like this-

[image]

And for your second issue just put some value in array to check that is working correctly or not.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` can be used with static cells? I received the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TransportExpenseCell0 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, the solution for me was:

- self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
- in storyboard, manually select all the static cells and change selection from "default" to "none"
- for those cells are allowed to be selected, change the selection to "Default".

It would appear as if only some cells can be selected.
You can still handle selection for those exclusive cells in didSelectRowAt by checking indexPath.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to programmatically insert the selection style setting for static cells, instead of using storyboard:

In viewWillAppear, use:

```
    tableView.cellForRow(at: yourIndexPath1)?.selectionStyle = .none
    tableView.cellForRow(at: yourIndexPath1)?.selectionStyle = .none
...
```